# Cannot install qrscanner gem on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ubuntu-12.04, qr-code

When running the gem install qrscanner, I'm having the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing qrscanner:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/kasuka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby extconf.rb

make
pwd ; cd zxing ; python scons/scons.py lib DEBUG=0 PIC=1
/home/kasuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/qrscanner-0.4.1/ext/qrscanner
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: warning: Two different environments were specified for target magick/src/MagickBitmapSource.o,
    but they appear to have the same action: $CXX -o $TARGET -c $CXXFLAGS $CCFLAGS $_CCCOMCOM $SOURCES
```

However when i added sudo:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing qrscanner:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
extconf.rb:4: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.

make
pwd ; cd zxing ; python scons/scons.py lib DEBUG=0 PIC=1
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/qrscanner-0.4.1/ext/qrscanner
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: warning: Two different environments were specified for target magick/src/MagickBitmapSource.o,
    but they appear to have the same action: $CXX -o $TARGET -c $CXXFLAGS $CCFLAGS $_CCCOMCOM $SOURCES
```

I'm using ruby 1.9.2 and is worth to mention that the extconf.rb file does not exist on neither of the location mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

> read the documentation of the gem at 
>   https://github.com/andys/qrscanner
>
> and install these dependencies before you install the gem.

```
Dependencies
------------

* Python (for ZXing build script)
* ImageMagick: libMagick++, libMagickWand, libMagickCore
* gcc, g++, libstd++
* Operating system with a PREFIX of "/usr".
```